# Magento2: Convert DataObject/Array into magento2 Collection?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, collection, object

How to convert the Data object into Magento2 Collection ?

In Mage1 we could do as below..

Mage1:

```
$collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();                
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $varienObject = new Varien_Object();
    $varienObject->setData($item);
    $collection->addItem($varienObject);
}
return $collection;
```

but how do in Mage2 ??

I know How set the DataObject But problem with Making the collection..

Comment: Have you try with, $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
    $postObject->setData($post);

Comment: @Rakesh That will create DataObject, So now I have Object which I want to convert into magento2 collection ..

Answer (score 10):

The collection class is `Magento\Framework\Data\Collection`, but you need to instantiate it using the autogenerated factory `Magento\Framework\Data\CollectionFactory`. Obtain it using the object manager or - preferred - by adding it as constructor parameter to the class where you use it (dependency injection)

Then your code becomes:

```
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $varienObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
    $varienObject->setData($item);
    $collection->addItem($varienObject);
}
return $collection;
```

Comment: but still its not giving all the methods available with core magento collection for example **getSelect()** is not available.

Comment: Of course not, this is the equivalent to `Varien_Data_Collection` which also does not have a `getSelect()` method. These are the basic collection classes, not the database specific collection classes, and the way you are using them, the database specific methods do not make sense.

Comment: filters are not working with Data Collection, I have gone to the method **addFieldToFilter** its returning nothing just throwing error ..any help ?

Comment: This seems to be a different question. Magento (1 and 2) can not filter a "loaded" collection

Comment: Magento2... this method is available with collection but throwing error

Comment: This does not work for me. I used Magento2.2.3. Have any solution? **@Fabian**

Comment: When I print `print_r($collection->getData());` data. It gives me an error.

Comment: Any solutions for that?